# How To Write LINQ Lambda Expression To Detect Intersect Specific DateTime Range

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

I having a logic as well as lambda statement problem.  Here is the scenario: I have a table named `CrewBooking`. This table's purpose is to record the booking that has been done by the customers. The rough format of the table is as shown below:

```
Crew ID       StartTime                     EndTime
================================================================
1008          2014-02-20 09:00 AM           2014-02-20 10:30 AM
1019          2014-02-20 11:00 AM           2014-02-20 12:30 PM
```

The problem is when the next crew want to make a booking, the system should be aware that the next booking should not intersect with the existing ones. Example, if the next booking is:

```
CrewID : 1008
StartTime 2014-02-20 10:00 AM
EndTime 2014-02-20 11:30 AM
```

the system should reject the given data because that new booking intersects with the first booking in the database.

How is possible to create a single lambda query in LINQ to cover this logic?

Comment: Do you only want to reject overlapping bookings with the same `CrewID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int CrewID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

Then a method could be written as follows:

```
var bookingToAdd = new Booking
{
    CrewID = 1008,
    StartTime = new DateTime(2014, 02, 20, 10, 00, 00),
    EndTime = new DateTime(2014, 02, 20, 11, 30, 00),
};

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var overlappingBookings = context.Bookings
        .Where(x => x.CrewID == bookingToAdd.CrewID)  // if you want to restrict it to the same crew
        .Where(x => x.StartTime <= bookingToAdd.StartTime && x.EndTime >= bookingToAdd.StartTime || x.StartTime <= bookingToAdd.EndTime && x.EndTime >= bookingToAdd.EndTime);

    if (overlappingBookings.Any())
    {
        //This new booking overlaps with an existing booking
    }
}
```

Comment: Another case which has not been considered above is where the new booking completely encloses an existing booking.